# iPhone sdk + HTTPS

Tags: iphone, https

How can I send an HTTPS request from within my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easiest to use the [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#creating_a_synchronous_request) framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have problems if the SSL cert for the https site is self signed.

If it is so, try this as the URL string: `https://username:password@host.com/`

This will work fine, I my self tried it.